# Rails 3 different types of embeds under one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails app that I am looking into implementing videos. I know how embed the videos etc but I am confuse on how to do something like this.

I would like a user to have videos. When a users goes to add a video I want to give them the option of embedding a youtube video or a vimeo video(Should I write out if statement?) without having 2 completely different urls.

**For example**
If user embeded a youtube video url would look like this

```
mysite.com/videos/1/youtube/1
```

If a user were to add video it would look like this

```
mysite.com/videos/1/youtube/new
```

What I would like to implement is the user would go to video and then have the choice of choosing vimeo or youtube. Ater the user has input the url of the video and click create i would like urls to look like(whether its youtube, vimeo or uploaded from cpu)

```
mysite.com/videos/1
mysite.com/videos/new
```

What is the best way to approach this? Would it be nested resources then rewrite the url paths?

Comment: Why not have one Video model, and add an attribute called 'provider'. 'provider' will act like a flag to specify youtube, vimeo, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured this out forgot to update question. Check out solution here 
[Vaildate 1 field with mutiple options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146231/vaildate-1-field-with-mutiple-options)

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this problem and I ended up using gem called [oembed](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/ruby-oembed) to handle processing of embedded files from youtube, vimeo etc.

Answer (score -1):

From a RESTful perspective, the resource that you are requesting is the video.  The mechanism of how that video is requested (whether that is Vimeo or Youtube) is irrelevant from the perspective of identifying the resource.  The format of the video being requested is simply a parameter of the request.  In your controller, you can decide how to render the video based on the parameters (or potentially other aspects of the request header).  Your video should clearly exist as a resource as

```
mysite.com/videos/1
```

Let the parameters or the HTTP request dictate how that is rendered.

Comment: The format of the video is not a parameter of the request. It is a property of the video itself. If I create a new video, and provide a vimeo link, then I should not be able to request that video as a youtube video.

Comment: That just makes your life easier.  You've got a show method associated with videos, and render the view that is appropriate based on the properties of the video.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question?  From a routing perspective, mysite.com/video/1 should refer to the video of ID = 1.  You can decide in either the controller or the view how to render it.

Comment: can someone write out an example as I am not understanding. I am new to rails. Should i write if statement like `<% if video %> do something vimeo else do something youtube<% end %>.`

Comment: Your controller presumably has a show action associated with videos.  In that show method, you know what video they are requesting.  At that point, you would retrieve the model, examine the model, and then decide which view to render (or you could decide to redirect to youtube).

Comment: @coletrain Yes, that is the right idea. I would suggest having partial views in your videos folder. Either way, you will probably do do something like `<% if @video.type == "youtube" %> ... <% elsif @video.type == "vimeo" %> ... <% end %>`

@MarcTalbot It really makes no sense to include the information as an addition parameter, or somewhere else in the header. It also violates RESTful practices. You want `/vidoes/1` to always fetch the video with id 1, even if no additional information is provided. Your method would maket his impossible.