# Vaildate 1 field with mutiple options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

So I have a rails app with a url field for embedding youtube and vimeo videos. Everything works fine but I cannot find a solution to validating both fields but only when one is used.

A user chooses a video url and has a choice of using vimeo or youtube and upon saving I would like to validate that the url code of the video(youtube or vimeo) is correct.

This is what I have

youtube validate code

```
validates :url ,
:format => {:with => /(https?):\/\/(www.)?(youtube\.com\/watch\?v=|youtu\.be\/)([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)(\&\S+)?.*/}
```

Vimeo validate code

```
validates :url ,
:format => {:with => /http:\/\/(www.)?vimeo\.com\/([A-Za-z0-9._%-]*)((\?|#)\S+)?/}
```

When I have the youtube code I cannot save a vimeo video and vice versa.

Both of the above codes work but only one, how can I have it so both work at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mash your regexes together into one big incomprehensible regex or you could use a custom validation method:

```
validate :youtube_or_vimeo_url

private

def youtube_or_vimeo_url
    return if(self.url =~ /\A(https?):\/\/(www.)?(youtube\.com\/watch\?v=|youtu\.be\/)([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)(\&\S+)?.*/)
    return if(self.url =~ /\Ahttp:\/\/(www.)?vimeo\.com\/([A-Za-z0-9._%-]*)((\?|#)\S+)?/)
    errors.add(:url, 'Bad video URL etc.')
end
```

You could also separate your two YouTube patterns with this approach and get code that is easier to read.

And while I'm here, if you're using a lot of slashes in your regexes you might want to use `%r{}` instead:

```
def youtube_or_vimeo_url
    return if(self.url =~ %r{\A(https?)://(www.)?(youtube\.com/watch\?v=|youtu\.be/)([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)(\&\S+)?.*})
    return if(self.url =~ %r{\Ahttp://(www.)?vimeo\.com/([A-Za-z0-9._%-]*)((\?|#)\S+)?})
    errors.add(:url, 'Bad video URL etc.')
end
```